# Ошибка кордовы Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK

Tags: cordova, ionic, ionicframework, ionic2

Моя версия cordova 6.3.1 и произошёл тупой глюк.
Выполняю cordova build --release android

```
Running command: /home/admin/ProgrammaJS/NEW/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/admin/ProgrammaJS/NEW
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=/home/admin/android-studio/
JAVA_HOME=/home/admin/jdk
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /home/admin/android-studio/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

Но версия SDK самая последняя android-studio-ide-145.3276617 и выпущена 19 сентября.Как чинить этот глюк

Comment: В директории /home/admin/android-studio/ должны быть директории platform-tools и build-tools, platforms. Если не так, неверно установлена переменная.

Comment: Там нет такого!Даже поиском в папке не находится. Качал архив весов 700 мегабайт

Answer (score 0):

Обычно при стандартных настройках SDK установится в $HOME/Android/Sdk, соответственно Вам надо поменять ANDROID_HOME

[image: пруф]

Comment: `admin@linux:~/ProgrammaJS/NEW$ cordova build --release android
Running command: /home/admin/ProgrammaJS/NEW/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/admin/ProgrammaJS/NEW
add to body class: platform-android
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.`

Comment: /NEW$ export ANDROID_HOME=~/android-studio
admin@linux:~/ProgrammaJS/NEW$ echo $ANDROID_HOME 
/home/admin/android-studio
admin@linux:~/ProgrammaJS/NEW$ cordova build --release android
Running command: /home/admin/ProgrammaJS/NEW/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/admin/ProgrammaJS/NEW
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=/home/admin/android-studio
JAVA_HOME=/home/admin/jdk
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /home/admin/android-studio/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
`

Comment: Вот такой вот баг

Comment: android-studio это и есть sdk

Comment: Android Studio в бандле включает себя SDK. При установке ставит его в отдельную директорию - см скриншот. SDK можно поставить и отдельно. Есть у вас в $HOME/Android/Sdk что-то?

Answer (score 0):

Страдал полтора часа в свое время.
Проблема в том, что градл надо было ручками ставить и самому.
Например этой тулзой(http://sdkman.io/install.html) эта одна строка:

```
sdk install gradle 4.0.2
```